# Webpack: One build and reuse with config or Build per environment

Tags: webpack, build

We have a webpack project that we currently build per environment. The build takes time and we want to optimize. The configurations (backend service URL, keys, etc.) and the publicPath differ by environment whereas the js code should ideally be the same.

So, Is it common to reuse the assets with only the configurations being set from the server-side in the HTML page that loads first?

We also see the publicPath could be used by webpack while building that can create issues with approach of reusing.

What is the best practice to build once, reuse across different environments via global config object that's rendered dynamically?